# return the first n multiples of the number x

Tags: javascript

Assuming that x is a positive integer, how would I return the first n multiples of the number x?

Here is what I have so far:

```js
function multiples(x, n){
  var arr=[];
  for (var i=1; i<=x; ++i)
    arr.push(n*i);
  return arr;
}


console.log(
  multiples(2, 5)
  );
```

What I want it to return is this: `multiples(2, 5) // [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

But what it actually returns is this: `[5, 10]`

Comment: You mistakenly swapped `x` and `n`. What you want is `multiples(5, 2)`.

Comment: That's when you know it is time to take a break, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You switched the `x` and the `n` in the  `for` loop

```js
//changed var to const & let

function multiples(x, n) {
  const arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    arr.push(x * i);
  return arr;
}

console.log(multiples(2, 5));
```

#### Using ES6 spread operator you can do like this:

```js
function multiples(x, n) {
  return [...Array(n)].map((_, i) => x * ++i);
}

console.log(multiples(2, 5))
```

#### Using ES6 Array.from(...) you can do like this:

```js
function multiples(x, n) {
  return Array.from(Array(n)).map((_, i) => x * ++i);
}

console.log(multiples(2, 5))
```

Comment: Upvoted but I liked the first answer the most, much more readable! :D

Comment: @MattiaRasulo I just wanted to give a few more ways to do it using  the "new javascript things" has to offer :)

Answer (score 1):

`x` swap `n`

```js
function multiples(x, n){
  var arr=[];
  for (var i=1; i<=n; ++i)
    arr.push(x*i);
  return arr;
}


console.log(
  multiples(2, 5)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You had the right idea, but swapped `x` and `n` in your loop:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    arr.push(x * i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const multiples = (x, n) => Array(n).fill().map((_, i) => x * ++i);

console.log(multiples(2, 5));
```